# fscanf-peforming arithmetic operations before storing integers into an array

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

Hey I'm trying to figure out if it's possible that 
the function fscanf operates on the integer that it has read from a file before storing it into an array.

For ex:

```
for(int i = 0 ;i < size;i++){
    //Here it just stores the number read
    fscanf(file, "%d", &arr[i]);
    //However I'm trying to do such a thing(substract the number by 1 everytime)
    fscanf(file, "%d -1 ", &arr[i]);
    printf("\n%d",arr[i]);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Uh..... No. No.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Read the input, then process it in your code.

Comment: It's not possible, but you can write a wrapper function or macro that does that if you want to: `#define FSCANF_SUBTRACT_1(FILE, FMT, VAR_PTR) do { int result = fscanf(FILE, FMT, VAR_PTR); --*VAR_PTR; return result; } while (false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't do what you need?

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    int temp;
    fscanf(file, "%d", &temp);
    arr[i] = temp - 1;

    printf("\n%d",arr[i]);
}
```